# Oracle SQL "Statement Ignored", and other error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am getting two errors on my procedure that I'm creating

The errors are:

1. Statement Ignored
2. ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Here is my code, the lines giving errors have comments on them:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_route_times(route IN VARCHAR2, day IN VARCHAR2, 
refcursor OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
cursorSend  sys_refcursor;  
BEGIN

    OPEN cursorSend FOR
SELECT RS.ROUTE_NO, RS.DIRECTION, RS.STOP_NAME, RS.JOURNEY_TIME, -- (ERROR 1 HERE)
    CASE
      WHEN lower(day)='sat' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
      WHEN lower(day)='sun' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
      ELSE to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
    END AS "1",
    CASE 
      WHEN lower(day)='sat' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sat.Frequency +       RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
       WHEN lower(day)='sun' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sun.Frequency + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
        ELSE to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+week.Frequency + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
      END AS "2",
    CASE
      WHEN lower(day)='sat' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sat.Frequency*2 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
       WHEN lower(day)='sun' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sun.Frequency*2 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
        ELSE to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+week.Frequency*2 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
      END AS "3",
          CASE
WHEN lower(day)='sat' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sat.Frequency*3 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
WHEN lower(day)='sun' THEN to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + sun.Frequency*3 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI') -- ERROR 2 on this line
        ELSE to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')+week.Frequency*3 + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440, 'HH24:MI')
      END AS "4"


     FROM BBT_ROUTESTOP RS
     INNER JOIN SATFREQ sat
     ON RS.ROUTE_NO = sat.ROUTE
     INNER JOIN SUNFREQ sun
     ON RS.ROUTE_NO = sun.ROUTE
     INNER JOIN WEEKFREQ week
      ON RS.ROUTE_NO = week.ROUTE
      WHERE lower(RS.ROUTE_NO)=lower(route)
      Order by RS.DIRECTION ASC;

      refcursor := cursorSend;
    END;
```

I've been looking at this for hours, sorry if this doesn't make sense, I hope you can help!

Thanks

Comment: Try renaming procedure parameter `day` to `i_day` everywhere.

Comment: The "ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined" tells you that there must be a field with the same name in some of the tables in the query, and you're not specifying which one it is, i.e. you missed the table alias (rs.field, sat.field, etc...)

Comment: You can refactor to make the code a lot less verbose: `to_char(trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440 + 3*CASE lower(day) WHEN 'sat' THEN sat.Frequency WHEN 'sun' THEN sun.Frequency ELSE week.Frequency END, 'HH24:MI') AS "4"`

Comment: About text `lower(day)`. Maybe you also have column `day` in table?

Comment: @JanisBaiza there is definately a `route` column in multiple tables and as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have `route` as a parameter to the stored procedure and it is also a column in your `SATFREQ`, `SUNFREQ` and `WEEKFREQ` tables and the query cannot work out which is which in the line: `WHERE lower(RS.ROUTE_NO)=lower(route)`.

Rename the parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_route_times(
  in_route   IN  VARCHAR2,
  in_day     IN  VARCHAR2, 
  out_cursor OUT sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN out_cursor FOR
  SELECT RS.ROUTE_NO,
         RS.DIRECTION,
         RS.STOP_NAME,
         RS.JOURNEY_TIME,
         to_char(
           trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440,
           'HH24:MI'
         ) AS "1",
         to_char(
           trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')
             + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440
             + 1 * CASE lower(in_day) WHEN 'sat' THEN Sat.FREQUENCY
                                      WHEN 'sat' THEN Sun.FREQUENCY
                                      ELSE Week.FREQUENCY END,
           'HH24:MI'
         ) AS "2",
         to_char(
           trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')
             + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440
             + 2 * CASE lower(in_day) WHEN 'sat' THEN Sat.FREQUENCY
                                      WHEN 'sat' THEN Sun.FREQUENCY
                                      ELSE Week.FREQUENCY END,
           'HH24:MI'
         ) AS "3",
         to_char(
           trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH')
             + RS.JOURNEY_TIME/1440
             + 3 * CASE lower(in_day) WHEN 'sat' THEN Sat.FREQUENCY
                                      WHEN 'sat' THEN Sun.FREQUENCY
                                      ELSE Week.FREQUENCY END,
           'HH24:MI'
         ) AS "4"
  FROM  BBT_ROUTESTOP RS
        INNER JOIN SATFREQ sat
        ON RS.ROUTE_NO = sat.ROUTE
        INNER JOIN SUNFREQ sun
        ON RS.ROUTE_NO = sun.ROUTE
        INNER JOIN WEEKFREQ week
        ON RS.ROUTE_NO = week.ROUTE
  WHERE lower(RS.ROUTE_NO) = lower( in_route )
  ORDER BY RS.DIRECTION ASC;
END;
```